# Getting a Type from another class

Tags: java, oop

So I got the bullet class:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Bullet extends GameObject
{
    private Player player;
    private int deltaX;

    public Bullet(final Player player, final int deltaX, final int xPos, final int yPos, final int width, final int height, final String img) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.player = player;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.rect = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        this.img = getImage(img);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos, width, height, null);
    }

    @Override
    void update(final Shooter shooter, final int id)
    {
        if(rect.intersects(player.rect))
        {
            shooter.bullets.remove(this);
            if(!(shooter.player1.getHull() == 0))
            {
                player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - 1);
                if(!(getStamina() <  1))
                    if(shooter.player1.getStamina() > 10)
                        shooter.player1.setStamina(shooter.player1.getStamina() - 10);
                    else
                        shooter.player1.setStamina(shooter.player1.getStamina() - 1);
                else
                    shooter.player1.setStamina(shooter.player1.getStamina() - 0);


            }
            else
            {
                player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - 2);

            }

            if(!(player.getHull() == 0))
                player.setHull(player.getHull() - 2);
            else
                player.setHull(player.getHull() - 0);
        }





        else if (yPos < -100 || yPos > 2000)
        {
            shooter.bullets.remove(this);
        }
        else
        {
            if(deltaX == 1)
            {
                yPos++;
                rect.y++;
            }
            else
            {
                yPos--;
                rect.y--;
                yPos--;
                rect.y--;
            }

        }

    }


    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public Player getPlayer()
    {
        return player;
    }

    @Override
    Image getImage(String img) {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img);
    }

    public int getDeltaX() {
        return deltaX;
    }

    public void setDeltaX(int deltaX) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
    }


}
```

And this is my Meteor class:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Meteor extends GameObject
{
    private Player player;
    private int deltaX;


    public Meteor(final Player player, final int deltaX, final int xPos, final int yPos, final int width, final int height, final String img) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.player = player;
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.rect = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        this.img = getImage(img);
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img, xPos, yPos, width, height, null);
    }

    @Override
    void update(final Shooter shooter, final int id)
    {
        if (yPos < -100 || yPos > 2000)
        {
            shooter.meteors.remove(this);
        }
        else
        {
            if(deltaX == 1)
            {
                yPos++;
                rect.y++;
            }
            else
            {
                yPos++;
                rect.y++;
            }
        }
        if(rect.intersects(shooter.player1.rect))
        {
            System.out.println("Collision");
            shooter.meteors.remove(this);
            shooter.player1.setHealth(shooter.player1.getHealth() - 100);
        }
    }


    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public Player getPlayer()
    {
        return player;
    }

    @Override
    Image getImage(String img) {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img);
    }

    public int getDeltaX() {
        return deltaX;
    }

    public void setDeltaX(int deltaX) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
    }


}
```

Now in the Meteor class i want to use this:

```
if(bullet.rect.intersect(shooter.player1.rect)
{..}
```

But this is not working because I cannot reference from it the bullet class. Is there any way to make it working?

This is the GameObject class

```
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class GameObject
{
    protected Rectangle rect;
    protected int xPos;
    protected int yPos;
    protected int height;
    protected int width;
    protected Image img;
    protected int health;
    protected int stamina;
    protected int hull;

    abstract void draw(Graphics g);

    abstract void update(final Shooter shooter, final int id);

    abstract Image getImage(String img);

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }
    public int getStamina() {
        return stamina;
    }

    public void setStamina(int stamina) {
        this.stamina = stamina;
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return rect;
    }

    public void setRect(Rectangle rect) {
        this.rect = rect;
    }

    public int getHull() {

        return hull;
    }

    public void setHull(int hull) {
        this.hull = hull;
    }

    public int getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public void setxPos(int xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }

    public int getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public void setyPos(int yPos) {
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }

    public Image getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rect seems to be a protected attribute of the `GameObject` class.

You can add a public getter in your `Bullet` class.

```
public Rectangle getRect() {
    return rect;
}
```

and then call it:

```
if(bullet.getRect().intersect(shooter.player1.rect))
```

Comment: I am sorry but that gives me an error. this is the gameobject class:

Comment: missing ) in if condition ?

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is

```
bullet.getRect().intersect(shooter.getPlayer().getRect())
```

A longer answer is

You need to give some thought to how your classes interact with each other. A book I would recommend is called "*Head First Design Patterns*."

One example is that you could simplify your code with a **delegate method** on the GameObject class. Your bullets, shooters, and meteors probably don't need to know or care whether the collision logic is implemented using `Rectangle`. Additionally, you might need to change your collision logic.

Sample method on `GameObject`

```
public boolean intersect (GameObject anotherObject) {
   return this.rect.intersect(anotherObject.rect);
}
```

Then your code would be

`bullet.intersect(shooter.getPlayer())`

Comment: This makes it crash for some reason: private Bullet bullet; i put this in the Meteor.java thing

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a reference to `Bullet` within `Meteor`. For instance create a property

> `private Bullet bullet;`// in this moment reference is not set up (it means bullet == null)

and set it by a defined by yourself setter method or pass a reference as a constructor parameter (depends on what are objects relations and your design).

`Rectangle` property of `Bullet` object should be defined as private/ protected and inside `Meteor` fetched by getter (because of encapsulation good pattern).

So it means

> `Rectangle rectangle = bullet.getRectangle();`

where `getRectangle()` is a defined, by you, getter for `rect` property.

Additionally I advice you to read about encapsulation.

At the beginning take a look here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: The reference to bullet in meteor makes it crash for some reason
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Meteor.<init>(Meteor.java:8)
 at Player.update(Player.java:214)
 at Shooter.paintComponent(Shooter.java:124)
 at Shooter.paint(Shooter.java:98)

Comment: NullPointerException means always that reference is not set up. See the line in code in which is reported exception and debug it to check what is a null there. I guess you can't get this exception in line 8 in current implementation, because these codes which you pasted have empty 8th line of Meteor. NullPointerException is thrown when you try to access object property, but you made a mistake and you didn't set reference. It's for sure simple to find the problem. Using debugger (for example within eclipse) can help in many even much more complicated cases.

Comment: Im using IntelliJ and don't know how to use it. Can you help me?

Comment: You can take a look here http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/compiler.html for the future. But I think in your case you don't need advanced debugging. You can try do simple thing. Assume that you have line which cause NullPointerException: question.getAnswers().getGoodAnswer(); :) you don't know which object is null, so you can try... System.out.println(question); then you will see if question is null. if not try... System.out.println(question.getAnswers()); if not try... System.out.println(question.getAnswers().getGoodAnswer()). Then you can see what causes null.

Comment: And if you would have time read a bit about java, the links I provided in my answer and the book which is in mentioned in @Aaron Kurtzhals answer is also great. But many books from head first series is very good. Which one is for you - depends on your knowledge level.

Comment: private Bullet bullet; bullet is null.. It says that it is never assigned to anything. When in the next line there is Rectangle rect = bullet.getRect(); So why is it giving out null?

Comment: What do i need to assign bullet to?